# Plot a bar chart with Seaborn library and group by function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

The requirement is to Plot a bar chart using a seaborn library, showing total sales (`Customer_Value`) by the `Last_region`. Here my code

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
customer = pd.read_csv('D:\PythonTraining\Customer.csv')

df = customer.groupby('Last_region')['Customer_Value'].sum()
df

sns.barplot(x = df.Last_region, y = df.Customer_Value)
plt.show
```

I get an error:

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'Last_region'.

How can I correct it? I believed after groupby, the attribute cant be referenced.

Comment: you can either `.reset_index()` after groupby or use `customer.groupby(..., as_index=False)`

Comment: `Last_region` becomes the index when you group by it, so you can use `x = df.index`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `Last_region` becomes the index when you group on it. Also note that `df` here is most likely a Series, not a DataFrame, in which case `Customer_Value` would also not be a column.

- Either use `x=df.index` and `y=df.values`

  ```
  sns.barplot(x=df.index, y=df.values)
  ```
- Or use `data=df.reset_index()` (now it's guaranteed to be a DataFrame with those columns)

  ```
  sns.barplot(data=df.reset_index(), x='Last_region', y='Customer_Value')
  ```

---

Alternatively, as Asish commented, you can change `df` so that `Last_region` is not the index:

- Either set `as_index=False` while grouping

  ```
  df = customer.groupby('Last_region', as_index=False)['Customer_Value'].sum()
  ```
- Or `reset_index()` after grouping

  ```
  df = customer.groupby('Last_region')['Customer_Value'].sum().reset_index()
  ```